# delete a submitted changelist from perforce history

Tags: perforce, changelist

I accidentally submitted a wrong changelist to my perforce server. I then backed out that changelist using the "backout changelist" option. But, these two changes appear in the history of all those affected files that they were once deleted and then added back again.

I want to be able to delete the history from perforce server of these two changelists. Is it possible. Can it be done via some Perforce administrator command.

EDIT: I have seen `p4 change -d -f` which can delete a changelist but this requires to use p4 obliterate on the files which were there in the changelist. Does this mean that I have to obliterate all the files which were affected by the changelist. This doesnt seem a viable solution for me as I do not want to delete those files. Should I only obliterate those specific two revisions of the files due to the two submitted changelists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your perforce administrator could call `p4 obliterate` to completely wipe out files, revisions and history.
But I'd strongly advise not to do so. It's a perfectly normal thing to rollback files/changes and to see the history of it.

In case you still decide to use `p4 obliterate` make sure you call it without the "-y" option first (preview) and then (if the output of what perforce says will happen is ok) call the same command with the "-y" option (to actually perform the obliterate).

If you call `p4 obliterate` with a file revision (e.g. `p4 obliterate //depot/dir/file#5`) then only the changes and history of that revision will be removed leaving all previous revisions and history intact. You can also obliterate a revision range.

Comment: actually that erroneous changelist affected almost each and every file, so the history has been damaged for almost all the files. That is why I do not want the rollback to appear. Do I have to call "p4 obliterate" for all the revisions of the affected files or only those two specific revisions (due to those two offending changelists)

Comment: IMHO no rollback justifies calling "p4 obliterate". It's a perfectly normal thing. If you still think you need it you have to call "p4 obliterate file#rev" for all files in the changelist. Add the "-y" option to really do it (leaving "-y" out just runs a test).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I understand that it may not seem logical to do a "p4 obliterate" but I still want to do it. So, I just need to obliterate the revision of the file which was introduced due to the erroneous changelist and not obliterate the whole file? Do I understand it right? I am asking it just for the confirmation.

Comment: Yes. "p4 obliterate -y //depot/dir/file#5" will just obliterate revision 5 of the file (leaving revisions 1-4). The history for #5 will be gone (including the changelist that introduced it).
You should run the command without "-y" for a testrun!
Make sure that no "#6" exists (revisions newer than the one you want to obliterate).
The obliterate command may block your server a little (i.e. submits will possibly take a longer time).

Comment: thanks. I have accepted your answer. Kindly edit it to include the information provided in the comments.

Comment: @pitseeker I want to obliterate a changelist which checked in lots of files and there is no real change in files. I can't seem to find the syntax of it. How can I obliterate a changelist? Thanks.

Comment: @pitseeker I can't type in all the file names that needs to obliterated. Can I do this only by changelist?

Comment: @zadane: The same means to specify revisions or revision ranges apply for obliterate than for all other commands. See "p4 help revisions". But since obliterate is such a dangerous command I always do it one by one (you can do it in a simple script actually).

Comment: @pitseeker you said "Make sure that no #6 exists" . Why is that? Will syncing to #6 fail if I obliterate #5?

Comment: @Himanshu: good question. I simply found it odd to obliterate old revisions and leave the head revision unobliterated. You get a gap in the history then. However I don't know if perforce permits that. In either way I assume perforce will continue to work consistently (with or without gap).

Comment: Thanks @pitseeker . I was afraid that the later revisions won't come because a prior one was gone. If Perforce works consistently, I am perhaps safe.

Comment: I still don't see a clear answer how to delete wrong commit to p4. I have a branch, I made accidental commit then I tried to backout, rollback etc. All of that just made it worse. All I want is to completely delete last 5 commits to my entire branch, exactly what git hard reset would do. Instead all I read are these multiple suggestions that it's ok to have all that mess. That was not the point of the question