# How to obliterate a changelist in perforce

Tags: perforce

I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to obliterate a changelist in perforce. The `p4 obliterate` is the key but it seem to require the file name. In my erroneous changelist there are lots of files so its not feasible to type them in. Can I obliterate by the changelist? I do see a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024386/delete-a-submitted-changelist-from-perforce-history) but they seem to do by file names + revision.

Note in my case I am obliterating the latest submission so I know there is nothing after it that's why its safe. I just need to grab it by changelist and not the 100+ files by name.

Comment: Do you actually need to obliterate the changelist from history (because you, say, checked in a file containing a hard-coded password)?  If you simply want to undo a change (because it broke something), you can back it out. http://kb.perforce.com/article/14/backing-out-submitted-changelists

Comment: @jamesdlin actually my checked in files have no change at all, they are identical to previous revision. It's just not clean when there is new revision of file but it has no change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

`p4 obliterate //...@=changelist`

The `//...` lets it run over any file (incredibly dangerous!) but the `@=` revision specifier limits it to the specific files included in that changelist.

Comment: So I guess if I do `p4 obliterate //...@=changelist` it should let me know what it will do without committing it?

Comment: Yes, if you don't provide the -y you'll get a preview of what would be obliterated.

Answer (score -2):

As a full answer, you will need to do this on command line, I don't see any way through UI.

To invoke command line go the perforce installation folder (usualy C:\Program Files\Perforce) and start windows command window here.

You will need to set the environment for command line so it works with your source database. I wish there was a way to start this from Perforce UI but I can't find it there. That way it would have probably set the environment variables already for you.

Run `p4 Set` command to see the environment variables and their current values (essentially perforce settings).

You will probably need to change `p4port` and `p4passwd`.

```
p4 set p4port=<your-src-server>:1666 // to configure server
```

Similarly change perforce password and username if needed. Now you should be able to connect to perforce server through command line.

Now you issue the obliterate command.